# How to include parent terms in hierarchical taxonomy URLs?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect, hierarchical

For all custom taxonomies, the URLs look like: **/base/slug/**.

I need a solution to for my hierarchical taxonomies to have: **/base/parentslug/childslug/**.

Anybody knows how to redirect and or to have the same functionality like categories?

Answer (score 4):

Just clarifying, what was pointed out by Parst with a working example of a custom taxonomy registration code:

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Issue numbers', 'taxonomy general name', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Issue number', 'taxonomy singular name', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search issues', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All issue numbers', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Year of publication', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Year of publication:', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit issue number', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update issue number', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add new issue number', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New issue number', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Issue numbers', 'sascha_setup_post_type' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'issues', 'hierarchical' => true ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'issue_number', array( 'post', 'issue' ), $args );
```

The result gives a url like www.yourdomain.com/issues/2016/04/ - just as you wanted it to be.
And! Don't forget to flush your permalink rules after implementing this, not to get 404 for your custom taxonomy urls. The easiest way - go to Admin / Permalinks and just hit the "save" button, without changing anything.

Comment: This is the answer. Adding `'hierarchical' => true` to my rewrite solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) documentation there is `rewrite/hierarchical` setting which controls that. It defaults to `false`, which is probably why you don't see it behaving same as native taxonomies.

Comment: Thanks for your note. But I already set the hierarchical parameter as "true" in the register taxonomy settings. The URL is still not using the parentslug.

Comment: @Traveler hmmm... flushed permalinks after? Note that this is not top-level `hierarchical` argument, this is `hierarchical` argument nested inside top-level `rewrite` one.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear, using rewrite/hierarchical like this **`"rewrite" => array("hierarchical" => true)`** on the $args array will add the parent slug of the taxomomy on the url automatically.

There no necessity to add rules for each term.

```
function type() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Type",
        "singular_name" => "Type",
        "menu_name" => "Type",
    );
    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "show_tagcloud" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rewrite" => array("hierarchical" => true)
    );
    register_taxonomy("type", array("products"), $args);
}
```