# Include parent and child in category url

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug

I've seen a lot of questions like this, bot none that could solve my problem.

For example: [How to include parent terms in hierarchical taxonomy URLs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155319/how-to-include-parent-terms-in-hierarchical-taxonomy-urls)

I've created a custom category with the `register_taxonomy` but could't make it work...

I can show my parent and child in the url now, but the parent doesn't matters...

What I mean is that this:
`http://localhost/collection/foo/childslug/` is the same as `http://localhost/collection/bar/childslug/`

Is that normal?

BTW: I've registered like this:

```
$args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'slug' => 'collectie' ),
    );
```

Comment: I've thrown up a simple answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289374/how-to-include-the-parent-and-child-category-in-the-permalink-if-the-post-is-add/ Let me know, is this helps you out.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. If the answer solved your problem, feel free to 'Up vote' it to let others know it works. :-) Good luck with your website!